# Iterating h1 using js

Tags: javascript

I need help using javaScript to iterate over this h1, giving each span a different color from an array. I tried this, but its giving every span the last color in the array.

```js
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];

const rainbow = document.querySelectorAll('h1');

for (let rain of rainbow) {
  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    rain.style.color = colors[i];
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>R</span>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>I</span>
  <span>N</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>O</span>
  <span>W</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close, the issue you have is that you are looping every `h1`, not the `span` within, you are also looping inside this, so, with the following code;

```js
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];

const rainbow = document.querySelectorAll('h1 span');
i = 0;
for (let rain of rainbow) {
  rain.style.color = colors[i];
  i++;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>R</span>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>I</span>
  <span>N</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>O</span>
  <span>W</span>
</h1>
```

You can see this working. What this does is the following;

- Get every `span` inside the `h1`
- Set a `i` variable to `0`
- For every span, add a color, then increment `i` by 1

Answer (score 1):

If you use `querySelectorAll` to also pick up the spans you can iterate over them (no need for a nested loop), and apply the colour to each one.

```js
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];

const spans = document.querySelectorAll('h1 span');

for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].style.color = colors[i];
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>R</span>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>I</span>
  <span>N</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>O</span>
  <span>W</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through `span`s not the `h1`, and get the corresponding `index` for each `span` in the `color` array.

```js
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];
const rainbow = document.querySelectorAll('span');
rainbow.forEach((rain, i) => rain.style.color = colors[i])
```

```html
<h1>
        <span>R</span>
        <span>A</span>
        <span>I</span>
        <span>N</span>
        <span>B</span>
        <span>O</span>
        <span>W</span>
    </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

look at your for loop... every item in h1 is being assigned the same color because they are all being run on the same for loop (iterating through all i values 0-6 therefore setting all items in h1 to the color violet).

try this instead...

```
    const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];
    const spans = document.querySelectorAll('h1 span');
    let count = 0;
    for (let rain in rainbows) {
       rain.style.color = colors[count];
       count += 1;
    }
```